# How do I get data from grid's row Ext JS

Tags: extjs, grid

How can I get data at certain row and column from Ext.grid.panel. suppose I want data at row X and column Y.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On some action :

```
grid.store.getAt(rowIndex).data.y
```

Here 'y' is dataIndex of particular column