# Get data from ExtJS grid row using selenium

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, extjs, selenium-webdriver

Currently there are couple links that suppose to help with this task: [general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107314/any-suggestions-for-testing-extjs-code-in-a-browser-preferably-with-selenium)(1) and [specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361790/how-do-i-get-data-from-grids-row-ext-js)(2) approached.

However (1) does not contain any code to start with and (2) contains only js one-liner.

My question is how to get values from extjs-generated row cells?

For example, I've row element

```
div#ext-gen-list-057-r.x-grid3-row.grid-rowcolor-black.grid-fontweight-normal.grid-fontstyle-normal.recordListRow.TableEvenRow.x-grid3-row-first.x-grid3-row-focus
```

where cells are represented like

```
td.x-grid3-col.x-grid3-cell.x-grid3-td-0.x-grid3-cell-first
```

How do I get it's values using python and selenium webdriver?

---

**UPD**

After some search there are few details revealed:

1. Seems like `browser.find_element(By.ID, 'element-id')` will simply not work for ExtJS webpage as soon as `document.getElementById('element-id')` is `null` (correct me if it's wrong)
2. Proper way of getting Ext page is `Ext.getBody('body-element-id')`

However, there is no such method for `Select` in `selenium.webdriver.support.ui` that will allow to access body elements.

Thus, the issue has not yet been resolved.

Comment: OT Easiest way to test ExtJS app https://www.sencha.com/products/test/

Answer (score 0):

May be this sample java code can help you. It doesn't directly answer your question, but you can easily convert it to python and also get an insight into solving your problem.

This code gets the extjs grid from the page, iterates through its rows to check if there is any cell containing the example id(1010294), then get the corresponding row and click the 8th cell on that row. 8th cell contains a button to click.

```
WebElement editCustTable = driver.findElement(By.className("x-grid-table"));
List<WebElement> tableRows = editCustTable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
for (Iterator iterator = tableRows.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    WebElement row = (WebElement) iterator.next();              
    // if tr contains id = '1010294'            
    if(row.getAttribute("id").contains("1010294")){
        List<WebElement> tds = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));
        tds.get(8).click();
        break;
        }       
    }
```